# Rewriting file reader in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, filereader, reader

I currently I have this piece of code which was originally a sample code online but edited slightly to fit my needs.

```
    <input type="file" id="files" name="file" />
<span class="readBytesButtons">
     <button>display injected files</button>
<span>
    <div id="displayedText"></div>

function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    console.log(files);
    if (!files.length) {
        alert('Please select a file!');
        return;
    }
    //var file = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(files[0], "UTF-8");

    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        try {
            var startWord = "inject";
            var endWord = "];";
            var injectedFilesString = evt.target.result.slice(evt.target.result.indexOf(startWord), evt.target.result.indexOf(endWord)) + "]";
            var injectedFiles = injectedFilesString.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(', ');

            document.getElementById("displayedText").innerHTML = injectedFiles
;            }
        catch(err) {
            document.getElementById("displayedText").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red; font-weight: bold; font-family: verdana;'>This file does not have any injected files within it.</span>";
        }
    }

    reader.onerror = function (evt) {
       alert("error reading file");
    }
  }

  document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
      var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
      var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
      readBlob(startByte, endByte);
      console.log(files);
    }
  }, false);
```

This piece of code currently reads and displays a certain portion of a file which is selected by the file selector tool. How could I change this code so that I don't need the file selector and could print portions of a file using a method such as fileName.injected();

Thanks, let me know if you have any clarifications

Comment: For browser security reasons, the _only_ access to files on a user's filesystem is through the file selection input

Comment: @Hamms Yes but could there possibly be any other way I can get a file's name into the function manually without having an input option?

Comment: A file's name? Yes. A file's content? no